# How to print out the value in view file?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

i have an array like that, i want to print out it in view file, but it's empty, array is like that

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'ProductsUserNode' => array(
        'product_user_node_id' => '155',
        'user_node_id' => '53',
        'product_id' => '1',
        'is_active' => '1',
        'expiry' => '0000-00-00',
        'created' => '2013-01-10 10:27:22',
        'modified' => '2013-01-10 10:27:22',
        'created_view' => '10:27 AM, Jan 10,2013',
        'modified_view' => '10:27 AM, Jan 10,2013'
    ),
    'UserNode' => array(
        'user_node_id' => '53',
        'division_id' => '28',
        'role_id' => '4',
        'user_id' => '56',
        'created' => '2013-01-10 10:27:20',
        'created_view' => '10:27 AM, Jan 10,2013'
    ),
    'Product' => array(
        'product_id' => '1',
        'name' => 'Manager',
    )
),
```

i am using this code in view file

```
              foreach ($products as $products)
             {
             ?>
            <tr>
                <td>    <?php $products['ProductsUserNode']['product_id']?> </td>
                <td>    <?php $products['Product']['name']?>    </td>
            </tr>
            <?php }?>
```

i have also set the variable in controllerlike that,

```
            $this->set('products',$products);
```

but it is not working, what's the problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: Show, How You set variable in Controller

Comment: shame on me i missed echo, w.t.f i m doing, no idea. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `echo` keyword to print your variables.

```
 foreach ($products as $product)
 {
 ?>
 <tr>
      <td>    <?php echo $product['ProductsUserNode']['product_id']?> </td>
      <td>    <?php echo $product['Product']['name']?>    </td>
 </tr>
 <?php }?>
```

Comment: Code is not enough, You need to give some explanation!

Answer (score 2):

> foreach ($products as $products) // wrong

You need to iterate over it properly (basic php!):

```
<?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td> <?php echo h($product['ProductsUserNode']['product_id']); ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo h($product['Product']['name']); ?> </td>
        </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Also note the h() to secure the view.

PS: You should "bake" your code. This way you would learn from it how do to it properly.